# Sending JSON Payload to Slack via AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda, httpresponse, slack

I am trying to build a Slack app by using AWS lambda and NodeJs. The issue I am facing is that I don't understand in what format does the SlackBot need the JSON payload from my AWS lambda code to display it.

I followed the tutorial video suggested on Slack linked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgFVzBNgidQ). In the video, the following JSON object is created and returned from the AWS lambda.

```
const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "Sample Response",
    };
```

The SlackBot posts the text entered in the 'body' property (i.e. 'Sample Response' in this case) as a response. This seems to be working well. But, I need some more flair than simple text so I looked into their [Block Kit UI builder](https://api.slack.com/block-kit/building). But there seems to be no documentation for how to do this with a similar 'response' JSON object like this. How exactly am I supposed to use the JSON object created by the UI builder?

I do not know much about Web development so sorry if this seems like a very basic question. I wish there was a sample Slack app on their website which showed this.

Answer (score 1):

The following may work for you (I use a similar one on the production);

```
{
  "channel": "your-channel-name",
  "username": "channel-username",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "title": "some-title",
      "fallback": "some message",
      "text": "some text",
      "fields": [
        {
          "title": "sub-title",
          "value": "sub-title-value",
          "short": true
        },
        {
          "title": "some-other-title",
          "value": "some-value"
        }
      ],
      "color": "red"
    }
  ],
  "icon_emoji": "gun"
}
```

This [link](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/layouts) or this [one](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) may provide some extra information.